# What is the difference between “that” and “the” in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, definite-articles, demonstratives

What is the difference between these two sentences:

> In that third week of November, I started school.

and

> In the third week of November, I started school.

Answer (score 2):

It's about context.

> In that third week of November, I started school.

means that something else happened in *that third week of November*. You are referring to a specific moment/event that happened in the past.

For instance:

> I'd been in labor for 7 days before my first son was born. In that third week of November, I started school.

While

> In the third week of November, I started school.

means you started school in the third week of November of the year you're talking about, which if cannot be thought out by context is usually the most recent November.

Comment: Is "in the third week of that November" more accurate than "in that third week of November"?

Comment: @math No. The only difference is that *that* is a demonstrative pronoun. It refers back to something that was mentioned in a previous sentence you haven't supplied. But if there' *isn't* a previous sentence that provides context, then using *that* in a standalone sentence is actually ungrammatical.

Comment: I think you'd meant to write ***I'd*** *been in labor for 7 days . . .*